# Need help in combine the Imagemagick Commands

Tags: imagemagick

mageMagick version
7.1.1-7

Operating system, version and so on is
Windows

Description
I have to create a gradient for an image I am using below commands, in two steps. In the first step I'm creating a gradient overlay image and applying that layoverimage to our source image. I need help in combining these two commands and make it in one execution.

1. `magick -size 100x200 -define gradient:direction=east gradient:black-none C:\Im-Test\Output\gradient\gr_12_baseGrad.png`
2. `convert C:\Im-Test\Output\Ketchup-S12.jpg C:\Im-Test\Output\gradient\gr_12_baseGrad.png -gravity West -composite C:\Im-Test\Output\gradient\G_Final_123.jpg`

Any help is appreciated.

Tried a couple of commands using `-Composite` and it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest you don't use convert in IM 7. Use Magick.  Does this do what you want?

```
magick C:\Im-Test\Output\Ketchup-S12.jpg ^
( -size 100x200 -define gradient:direction=east gradient:black-none ) ^
-gravity West -composite C:\Im-Test\Output\gradient\G_Final_123.jpg
```

Be sure there is a space on either side of each parenthesis. The above is a 3-line single command. The ^ indicate new line after it. So copy and past as is in 3 lines.  You may remove the ^s but then make sure the command is on one single line of text.

```
magick C:\Im-Test\Output\Ketchup-S12.jpg ( -size 100x200 -define gradient:direction=east gradient:black-none ) -gravity West -composite C:\Im-Test\Output\gradient\G_Final_123.jpg
```

See https://imagemagick.org/Usage/basics/#parenthesis